# Problems with working shield in pygame platformer

Tags: python, pygame

Been messing around with Pygame for a while now and I wanted to make a 2d game where the player has the access to a shield which will only block enemy bullets if they are the same colour as the shield itself. I've been stuck on this problem a good few weeks now and was hoping anyone on here would be able to help me if possible. This is my first post on this website so I'm sorry if it's not the best.
This is a shortened down version of the code located below ….

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]

walkRight2 = [pygame.image.load('R1E.png'), pygame.image.load('R2E.png'), pygame.image.load('R3E.png'),
              pygame.image.load('R4E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'), pygame.image.load('R6E.png'),
              pygame.image.load('R6E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'), pygame.image.load('R4E.png')]
walkLeft2 = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'),
             pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L6E.png'),
             pygame.image.load('L6E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L4E.png')]

bg = pygame.image.load('Bg_1.png').convert()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isjump = False
        self.jumpcount = 10
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkcount = 0
        self.standing = True
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y + 15, self.width - 40, self.height - 20)
        self.right_shield = (self.x + 15, self.y, self.width - 35, self.height)
        self.left_shield = (self.x + 17, self.y, self.width - 35, self.height)
        self.lifes = 35
    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkcount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkcount = 0

        if not (self.standing):
            if self.left == True:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkcount += 1
            elif self.right == True:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkcount += 1
        else:
            if self.right == True:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y + 15, self.width - 40, self.height - 20)
        self.right_shield = (self.x + 15, self.y, self.width - 35, self.height)
        self.left_shield = (self.x + 17, self.y, self.width - 35, self.height)
    def hit(self, win):
        global run
        global bad_guys_kiled
        if self.lifes > 0:
            self.lifes -= 1
            if self.lifes % 2 == 0:
                pass
        if self.lifes <= 0:
            run = False
            print("You have ran out of lifes!")
            print("Thank you for playing!")

class enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.boss_vel = 2
        self.left = True
        self.right = False
        self.walkcount = 0
        self.isjump = False
        self.jumpcount = 10
        self.standing = True
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y + 10, self.width - 40, self.height - 20)
        self.shootloop1 = 0
        self.bullets2 = []
        self.bullets3 = []
        self.lifes = 2
        self.half_health = False
    def draw(self, win):
        global half_health
        global bad_guys_kiled
        if bad_guys_kiled <= 25:
            if self.walkcount + 1 >= 27:
                self.walkcount = 0
            if not (self.standing):
                if self.left == True:
                    win.blit(walkLeft2[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                    self.walkcount += 1
                elif self.right == True:
                    win.blit(walkRight2[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                    self.walkcount += 1
            else:
                if self.right == True:
                    win.blit(walkRight2[0], (self.x, self.y))
                else:
                    win.blit(walkRight2[0], (self.x, self.y))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y + 10, self.width - 40, self.height - 20)
            enemy_health = (self.x + 25, self.y + 5, self.width - 40, self.height - 70)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), enemy_health)
            if self.half_health == True:
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.x + 50, self.y + 5, self.width - 75, self.height - 70))
    def draw2(self, win):
        global half_health
        global bad_guys_kiled
        if self.walkcount + 1 >= 27:
            self.walkcount = 0
        if not (self.standing):
            if self.left == True:
                win.blit(walkLeft2[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkcount += 1
            elif self.right == True:
                win.blit(walkRight2[self.walkcount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkcount += 1
        else:
            if self.right == True:
                win.blit(walkRight2[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkRight2[0], (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y + 10, self.width - 40, self.height - 20)

        enemy_health = (self.x + 25, self.y + 5, self.width - 40, self.height - 70)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), enemy_health)
        if self.half_health == True:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.x + 50, self.y + 5, self.width - 75, self.height - 70))
    def walk(self, win):
        global shield
        global drop_spot
        global drop
        global shield_health
        global bad_guys_kiled
        global temp_num
        global temp_number
        global colours
        global shield_colour
        global shield_number
        global bullet_colour
        global test_number
        bullet_colour = random.choice(colours)
        if bullet_colour == "blue":
            colour_number = (0, 0, 255)
            test_number = 0
        else:
            colour_number = (255, 0, 0)
            test_number = 1
        if temp_num == False:
            temp_number = random.randint(4, 34)
            temp_num = True
        if self.shootloop1 > 0:
            self.shootloop1 += 1
        if self.shootloop1 > int(temp_number):
            self.shootloop1 = 0
        if bad_guys_kiled <= 25 and not (main_menu):
            for bullet in self.bullets2:
                if man.left:
                    if int(shield_number) == int(test_number):
                        if bullet.y - bullet.radius < man.right_shield[1] + man.right_shield[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > man.right_shield[1]:
                            if bullet.x + bullet.radius > man.right_shield[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < man.right_shield[0] + man.right_shield[2]:
                                try:
                                    self.bullets2.pop(self.bullets2.index(bullet))
                                except ValueError:
                                    pass
                elif man.right:
                    if int(shield_number) == int(test_number):
                        if bullet.y - bullet.radius < man.left_shield[1] + man.left_shield[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > man.left_shield[1]:
                            if bullet.x + bullet.radius > man.left_shield[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < man.left_shield[0] + man.left_shield[2]:
                                try:
                                    self.bullets2.pop(self.bullets2.index(bullet))
                                except ValueError:
                                    pass
                elif int(shield_number) != int(test_number):
                    if bullet.y - bullet.radius < man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > man.hitbox[1]:
                        if bullet.x + bullet.radius > man.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2]:
                            man.hit(win)
                            try:
                                self.bullets2.pop(self.bullets2.index(bullet))
                            except ValueError:
                                pass
                if bullet.x < 800 and bullet.x > -50:
                    bullet.x += bullet.vel
                else:
                    try:
                        self.bullets2.pop(self.bullets2.index(bullet))
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
            if self.left:
                facing = -1
            elif self.right:
                facing = 1
            if len(self.bullets2) < 7 and self.shootloop1 == 0:
                self.bullets2.append(projectile(round(self.x + self.width // 2), round(self.y + self.height // 2), 6, (colour_number),facing))
                self.shootloop1 = 1
            if self.x != -50:
                self.x -= self.vel
                self.right = False
                self.left = True
                self.standing = False
            else:
                for x in range(1, 200):
                    if self.x >= 700:
                        self.x = 650
                    self.half_health = False
                    self.x += self.vel
                    self.right = False
                    self.left = True
                    self.standing = False
        else:
            for bullet in self.bullets2:
                try:
                    self.bullets2.pop(self.bullets2.index(bullet))
                except ValueError:
                    pass

    def hit(self, win):
        global bad_guys_kiled
        global drop
        global drop_spot
        global drop_count
        global min
        global max
        global score
        Hit_noise.play()
        if self.lifes > 0:
            self.lifes -= 1
            self.half_health = True
        if self.lifes <= 0:
            random_number = random.randint(min, max)
            if bad_guys_kiled <= 25:
                if random_number == 1:
                    if drop_count != 1:
                        drop = True
                        drop_count += 1
                        drop_spot = [self.x + 20]
                        drop_spot += [self.y + 10]
                        drop_spot += [self.width - 40]
                        drop_spot += [self.height - 40]
                    else:
                        try:
                            max -= 1
                        except ValueError:
                            max = 20
            if bad_guys_kiled >= 25:
                drop_spot = []

            self.half_health = False
            self.x = self.x + 700
            self.lifes = 2
            bad_guys_kiled += 1
            score += 1

class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, colour, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.colour = colour
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.colour, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
def redraw_game_window():
    global drop_spot
    global drop
    global bad_guys_kiled
    global jump_block
    global main_menu
    global run
    global count
    global score
    global shield
    global man_movement_block
    global shield_colour
    global bullet_colour
    global test_number
    global shield_number
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    man.draw(win)
    print("man = ",shield_number)
    print("bullet =",test_number)
    text_score = font.render("Score:" + str(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    text_shield = font.render("Shield Colour:" + "temp", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    text_player_health = font.render("Player Health:" + str(man.lifes), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(text_score, (450, 10))
    win.blit(text_shield, (225, 10))
    win.blit(text_player_health, (20, 10))

    if bad_guys_kiled <= 25:
        if drop == True:
            try:
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (drop_spot[0], drop_spot[1], drop_spot[2], drop_spot[3]))
            except IndexError:
                pass
    if man.left == True and shield_colour == "blue":
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (man.x + 17, man.y, man.width - 35, man.height), 2)
    elif not(main_menu) and shield_colour == "blue":
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (man.x + 15, man.y, man.width - 35, man.height), 2)
    if man.right == True and shield_colour == "red":
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (man.x + 17, man.y, man.width - 35, man.height), 2)
    elif not(main_menu) and shield_colour == "red":
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (man.x + 15, man.y, man.width - 35, man.height), 2)
    if bad_guys_kiled <= 25 :
        bad_guy1.draw(win)
        bad_guy2.draw(win)
        bad_guy3.draw(win)

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
    for bullet in bad_guy1.bullets2:
        bullet.draw(win)
    for bullet in bad_guy2.bullets2:
        bullet.draw(win)
    for bullet in bad_guy3.bullets2:
        bullet.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()

def game_credits():
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (40, 26, 13), (0, 0, 650, 650))
    text_help = font.render("CONTROLS", 1, (0, 255, 0))
    text_help1 = font.render("UP ARROW = JUMP", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    text_help2 = font.render("LEFT ARROW = LEFT", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    text_help3 = font.render("RIGHT ARROW = RIGHT", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    text_help4 = font.render("ZERO ON NUMPAD = FIRE", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    text_help5 = font.render("P = PAUSE", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    text_help6 = font.render("O = UNPAUSE ", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    text_help7 = font.render("(PRESSING P WILL NOT ", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    text_help8 = font.render("UNPAUSE THE GAME !)", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    text_help9 = font.render("B = SHIELD", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    win.blit(text_help, (22, 50))
    win.blit(text_help1, (22, 100))
    win.blit(text_help2, (22, 150))
    win.blit(text_help3, (22, 200))
    win.blit(text_help4, (22, 250))
    win.blit(text_help5, (22, 300))
    win.blit(text_help6, (22, 350))
    win.blit(text_help7, (22, 400))
    win.blit(text_help8, (22, 450))
    win.blit(text_help9, (22, 500))
# Main Loop #
Air_raid = pygame.mixer.Sound("Air raid.wav")
Godzilla_roar = pygame.mixer.Sound("Godzilla roar.wav")
Victory_noise = pygame.mixer.Sound("Victory noise.wav")
Gun_shot = pygame.mixer.Sound("Gun shot.wav")
Hit_noise = pygame.mixer.Sound("Hit noise.wav")
man = player(300, 450, 64, 64)
bad_guy1 = enemy(0, 450, 64, 64)
bad_guy2 = enemy(250, 450, 64, 64)
bad_guy3 = enemy(500, 450, 64, 64)
count = 0
bullets = []
shootloop = 0
bad_guys_kiled = 0
temp_num = False
temp_number = 0
drop = False
drop_spot = []
drop_count = 0
min = 1
max = 20
main_menu = False
main_spawn = False
score = 0
man_movement_block = False
shield_count = 0
colours = ["blue", "red"]
shield_colour = "blue"
bullet_colour = None
shield_number = 0
test_number = 0
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri Light", 25, True)
run = True
while run == True:
    temp_number = random.randint(4, 34)
    if man.y >= 500:
        man.y = 450
    clock.tick(27)
    shield = True
    if shootloop > 0:
        shootloop += 1
    if shootloop > 5:
        shootloop = 0
    if shield_count > 0:
        shield_count += 1
    if shield_count > 5:
        shield_count = 0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bad_guys_kiled <= 25:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < bad_guy1.hitbox[1] + bad_guy1.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > bad_guy1.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > bad_guy1.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < bad_guy1.hitbox[0] + bad_guy1.hitbox[2]:
                    bad_guy1.hit(win)
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < bad_guy2.hitbox[1] + bad_guy2.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > bad_guy2.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > bad_guy2.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < bad_guy2.hitbox[0] + bad_guy2.hitbox[2]:
                    bad_guy2.hit(win)
                    try:
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < bad_guy3.hitbox[1] + bad_guy3.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > bad_guy3.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > bad_guy3.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < bad_guy3.hitbox[0] + bad_guy3.hitbox[2]:
                    bad_guy3.hit(win)
                    try:
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    except ValueError:
                        pass

        try:
            if man.hitbox[1] - (man.hitbox[3] / 2) < drop_spot[1] + (drop_spot[3] / 2) and man.hitbox[1] + (man.hitbox[3] / 2) > drop_spot[1]:
                if man.hitbox[0] + (man.hitbox[3] / 2) > drop_spot[0] and man.hitbox[0] - (man.hitbox[3] / 2) < drop_spot[0] + drop_spot[2]:
                    Gun_shot.stop()
                    if man.lifes <= 35:
                        man.lifes += 10
                    else:
                        Gun_shot.stop()
                        pass
                    try:
                        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                        drop = False
                        drop_count = 0
                        drop_spot = []
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
        except:
            pass
        if bullet.x < 650 and bullet.x > -20:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            try:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_KP0] and not (main_menu):
        if man.left:
            facing = -1
        elif man.right:
            facing = 1
        else:
            facing = -1
        if len(bullets) < 5 and shootloop == 0:
            Gun_shot.play()
            bullets.append(projectile(round(man.x + man.width // 2), round(man.y + man.height // 2), 6, (0, 0, 255), facing))
            shootloop = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel and not(man_movement_block):
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 620 - man.vel - man.width:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_b] and shield_count == 0:
        if shield_colour == "blue":
            shield_colour = "red"
            shield_number = 1
        else:
            shield_colour = "blue"
            shield_number = 0
        shield_count = 1
    if not (man.isjump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            man.isjump = True
            man.walkcount = 0

    else:
        if man.jumpcount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpcount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpcount ** 2) / 2 * neg
            man.jumpcount -= 1
        else:
            man.isjump = False
            man.jumpcount = 10

    bad_guy1.walk(win)
    bad_guy2.walk(win)
    bad_guy3.walk(win)

    redraw_game_window()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I've tried running the example code but it is rife with `NameError`s. Please make sure the example code runs on it's own so that question answerers can focus on the actual problem. (Your question implies that it runs for you and that getting it to run is not the issue.)

Comment: I've been having troubles making the code fit the character limit of the website, I will however try a upload it so that you can have a look and see if you can fix the problem, thank you

Comment: Also, please tell us what you want the code to do and how your current version differs from that. Just "not working" is not sufficient.

Comment: Okay sorry I'll try and be more specific next time , basically I want the player to register as being hit (by calling the man.hit function) when an enemy bullet (the elements in the bullet2 list) are the same colour as the players shield, which is currently being stored as both a word (i.e "blue" and a RGB value.). Currently no matter what colour the "bullets" are it will not accurately detect the colour of the "shield" and "bullet" being either the same or different, the error must be were I am checking the colours of the two items due to it working fine before I tried adding this feature.

Comment: Again I am sorry if I appear to be wasting your time, I am as stated new to this website and struggle both on the web and IRL to communicate what I am trying to do with my code to other people. I massively appreciate the fact you are actually trying to help me out and have not just left me to struggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the code in the `walk` method of the `enemy` class, where you check for collisions between enemy bullets and the player.

```
if man.left:
    ... # block bullets with the shield when the player is pointing left
elif man.right:
    ... # block bullets with the shield when the player is pointing right
elif int(shield_number) != int(test_number):
    ... # if the player has been hit, call man.hit
```

Because you have used an `elif`, the code that checks if the player has been hit (and calls `man.hit`) will only be executed if both `man.left` and `man.right` are false, which never happens. Just changing it from an `elif` to an `if` should solve your problem.

```
if man.left:
    ... # block bullets with the shield when the player is pointing left
elif man.right:
    ... # block bullets with the shield when the player is pointing right

if int(shield_number) != int(test_number):
    ... # if the player has been hit, call man.hit
```

Comment: sorry for the late response I forgot to thank you for your help in solving this problem !

Comment: I am very grateful for your help !

Comment: You're welcome :) If this answered your question you can mark it as the answer. No pressure if it wasn't though!